# Why BackgroundWorker started itself?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

In my application `backgroundWorker` starts when I start the application. I can't see anything before `backgroundworker_dowork` in call stack other than [external code].

Why backgroundworker is starting itself and how to avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BackgroundWorkers are started by calling the worker's [RunWorkerAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).  Find where this method is being called, breakpoint it and see what's what.